# compare multiple columns within same file and print difference

Tags: awk, compare, match

I have a large file and want to compare multiple columns.

Trial version of [Input dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IanxrwfoXzpXngH7mFjWf6oCxLNhIRQq/view?usp=sharing):

[image]

I want to compare column 6 with  column 8 and column 7 with column 9 and want to remove the lines that match.
command tried:

```
awk '($6 != $8)&&($7 != $9){print $0}' input > output
```

It doesn't work to print difference, however it works if I want to print match (awk '($6 == $8)&&($7 == $9){print $0}' input > output)

So the desired output should be:

[image: desired output1]

Comment: Please do not post data in form of images, post them always in form of text in CODE TAGS so that we need not to write them manually while testing solutions, kindly do the same and let us know then.

Comment: I always paste in the form of text but this time it didn't allow me to paste from excel sheet, that's why I pasted the image and provided the input dataset as a hyperlink.

Comment: Not sure, may be you haven't wrapped it in CODE TAGS, try editing it once?

Comment: Tried but unfortunately, it's not working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a == b && c == d
```

Negation of it is:

```
! (a == b && c == d)
a != b || c != d
```

You should learn about [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

```
awk '$6 != $8 || $7 != $9 {print $0}'
```

or just:

```
awk '!( $6 == $8 && $7 == $9 ){print $0}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following once.

`awk '($6 == $8){if($7 == $9){next}} 1'  input > output`

OR as per Ed sir's comment a little more awkish:

`awk '$6==$8 && $7==$9{next} 1'  Input_file > output`

Comment: If setting FS to tab was the issue then the OPs existing code would have worked since tab is included when using the default FS. The `&&` should be  an `||`

Comment: The OPs question states that `($6 == $8)&&($7 == $9)` prints the matching lines. Now see [@KamilCuk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58167114/1745001) for how to negate that condition to print the non-matching lines which is what the OP actually wants to do.

Comment: @Ed Morton, Thank you for guiding, changed solution now, little more awkish style. I am in cab so didn't test but should work I believe :)

Comment: `($6 == $8){if($7 == $9){next}} 1` is more awkishly `($6 == $8) && ($7 == $9){next} 1`

Comment: @Waqas Khokhar, could you please try my edited answers now and let me know.